# I adding in my admin panel multiple images. And when I fetch api to get these images as slider. Result is "Request failed with status code 403"

Tags: reactjs, slider, crud, react-icons

This is my code and in section slider i'm trying to make slider images but i don't know what's problem?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import styles from "./style.module.css";
import { MdArrowBackIos, MdArrowForwardIos } from "react-icons/md";



export default function Main() {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
  const [secondData, setSecondData] = useState([]);

  const token = "mrfcaiL5UrlAu_zsWeADkwKKXFLxJK41";



  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchSecondData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          "http://130.61.61.186:8055/items/Slider",
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
          }
        );
        setSecondData(response.data.data);
        console.log(response.data.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };

    fetchSecondData();
  }, []);

  const handleNext = () => {
    setActiveIndex((prevIndex) =>
      prevIndex === secondData.length - 1 ? 0 : prevIndex + 1
    );
  };

  const handlePrev = () => {
    setActiveIndex((prevIndex) =>
      prevIndex === 0 ? secondData.length - 1 : prevIndex - 1
    );
  };

  return (
    <main>
      <article className={styles.sections}>
       
        <section className={styles.slider}>
          {secondData.map((item) => (
            <div key={item.id}>
              <MdArrowBackIos
                className={styles.leftArrow}
                onClick={handlePrev}
              />
              <MdArrowForwardIos
                className={styles.rightArrow}
                onClick={handleNext}
              />

              <img
                src={
                  "http://130.61.61.186:8055/assets/" +
                  item.images +
                  "?access_token=mrfcaiL5UrlAu_zsWeADkwKKXFLxJK41"
                }

                className={styles.image}
              />
            </div>
          ))}
        </section>
       
      </article>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Result is nothing. In console only this:
AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 403', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code
:
"ERR_BAD_REQUEST"
config
:
{transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}
message
:
"Request failed with status code 403"
name
:
"AxiosError"
request
:
XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
response
:
{data: {…}, status: 403, statusText: 'Forbidden', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}
stack
:
"AxiosError: Request failed with status code 403\n    at settle (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:232122:12)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:230813:66)"
[[Prototype]]
:
Error

Comment: It seems like you're making a cross-site GET request, which does not include Authorization headers by default (look at `withCredentials: false` in the error). Try passing it to the request: `axios.get(url, { headers, withCredentials: true })`